# Equidistant points on canvas

Tags: javascript, math, html, canvas

I want to draw a variable number of equidistant points on a HTML5 canvas element, using JavaScript. How do I calculate the X/Y position of each point?

*EDIT:*

I want the distance from one point to its direct neighbours and to the edges of the canvas to be the same.
If I had an 8px x 8px canvas and 4 points, the distace from a point to it's direct neighbours and to the edges of the canvas would be 2px.
But what if i had an uneven number of points and not a square canvas?
(i think an image might help to understand my problem a little better)

[image: equidistant points]

Comment: The term "direct neighbors" is a little bit vague in this context. You need a better definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. I guess you're right. I need to do some sketching before I can give you a better definition of 'direct neighbours'...

Comment: What about this one: M={p_1, p_2, ..., p_n} are said to have have equal distance d iff: for each p_i element M:  p_i has distance <= d from nearest edge and there exists p_j element M such that |p_i - p_j| = d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend building a simple constraint solver - using relaxation to arrive at the answer you want.  This is similar to the technique used by some Visio-like applications.  Basically, you can add spring forces between the pairs of points and the boundaries of the canvas.  You simulate for a short amount of time, and everything will 'settle' into place.

You could try Box2DJS - a simple javascript physics system.  Or read up on Verlet integration / constraints - it's pretty simple to get up and running, and great for these kinds of applications.

Answer (score 1):

@snorpey - what you are asking is basically to arrange the points such that, given a radius R, all points are centers of circles of radius R, where:

1. All "direct neighbors" (this needs a better definition) are ON the circumference;
2. All circles of points near the edges are tangent to the nearest edge(s).

My intuition says that this requirement may be impossible to meet given an arbitrary number of points, and given a more strict definition for a neighbor, but I can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean a series of points all equidistant from the last on a line then you just need to take the total distance between the start point and end point along the x and y axis and divide that by the total

so to get point n (xn and yn with x0 and y0 being the start) you can do

xn = ((xend - x0) / number_of_points) * n

same for y.

Comment: better yet, you can just fix the delta and add that to the coordinates of the last point.

Answer (score 0):

If I look at you diagram with the label "x px" and try to identify the "direct neighbours" I need some help. If we take the point in the centre and try to identify its DN's all of the othe rpoints in the diagram could be DN's. How can the ones you want be identified?